# Rust importing a function from lib.rs

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cywST.png)

I have few functions in my lib.rs inside a module "game" which I have names as "mylib.rs" .  Now when I try to import this to main.rs i.It throws an error.

```
use std::io;
  mylib::game::build_vector;
  mylib::game::build_instance;
  mylib::game::roll_dice;
  mylib::game::Player;
```

Comment: You may find the Rust documentation on [modules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/rust-by-example/mod.html) to be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

When importing something, the `use` keyword is required:

```rust
use std::io;
use mylib::game::build_vector;
use mylib::game::build_instance;
use mylib::game::roll_dice;
use mylib::game::Player;
```

If you like it shorter, you can write nested use declarations with curly braces:

```rust
use std::io;
use mylib::game::{build_vector, build_instance, roll_dice, Player};
```